# Return value greater than 255 in the shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using one shell script. It has the return value(output). But in that linux box, if the return value is greater than 255 , it treating as 256=1, 257=2 etc., plese let me know the changes needs to be done to get the actual return value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is a constraint on shell exit code that the value should be between 0 ~ 255 (see [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Bash_shell_and_script), I didn't find any clues from the official man page). So I think you cannot change the range of exit code.

However, I think 255 (1~255) different values can satisfy most requirements. Could you please explain what you want to do with exit code 256? Or you can subtract some constant from the return code yourself, e.g. `n - 128` where `n` is your exit code like 256.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this if you are making some scripting would be to `echo` the output you want as return and catch it with `eval`. It can even be something else than a number.

```
local return=$(eval "functionToCall \"$thisIsAParam\"")
```